# SwiftLint exclude, disabled rule not working?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

We are following the instruction from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint.

1. In terminal CD->PROJECT DIRECTORY
2. touch .swiftlint.yml
3. open .swiftlint.yml

and added following rules

```
# By default, SwiftLint uses a set of sensible default rules you can adjust:
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers turned on by default to exclude from running
  - colon
  - comma
  - control_statement
  – compiler_protocol_init
  – cyclomatic_complexity
  – file_length
  – force_cast
  – function_body_length
  – function_parameter_count
  – identifier_name
  – multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure
  – notification_center_detachment
  – line_length
  – trailing_whitespace
  – type_body_length
  – type_name
  – todo
  - shorthand_operator
opt_in_rules: # some rules are turned off by default, so you need to opt-in
  - empty_count # Find all the available rules by running: `swiftlint rules`

# Alternatively, specify all rules explicitly by uncommenting this option:
# only_rules: # delete `disabled_rules` & `opt_in_rules` if using this
#   - empty_parameters
#   - vertical_whitespace

included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
  - Kuwy
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - Source/ExcludedFolder
  - Source/ExcludedFile.swift
  - Source/*/ExcludedFile.swift # Exclude files with a wildcard
analyzer_rules: # Rules run by `swiftlint analyze` (experimental)
  - explicit_self

# configurable rules can be customized from this configuration file
# binary rules can set their severity level
force_cast: warning # implicitly
force_try:
  severity: warning # explicitly
# rules that have both warning and error levels, can set just the warning level
# implicitly
line_length: 500
# they can set both implicitly with an array
type_body_length:
  - 300 # warning
  - 400 # error
# or they can set both explicitly
file_length:
  warning: 500
  error: 1200
# naming rules can set warnings/errors for min_length and max_length
# additionally they can set excluded names
type_name:
  min_length: 4 # only warning
  max_length: # warning and error
    warning: 40
    error: 50
  excluded: iPhone # excluded via string
  allowed_symbols: ["_"] # these are allowed in type names
identifier_name:
  min_length: # only min_length
    error: 4 # only error
  excluded: # excluded via string array
    - id
    - URL
    - GlobalAPIKey
reporter: "xcode" # reporter type (xcode, json, csv, checkstyle, codeclimate, junit, html, emoji, sonarqube, markdown, github-actions-logging)
```

In BuildPhase added the following script

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

and tried following script also

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

But still I am getting errors, and Pods directory not excluded. Somebody please help on this.

Please find the SS[image: Error Image]

Is there any other configuration missing?

I have installed SwiftLint by following ways

Using Homebrew:

```
brew install swiftlint
```

Using CocoaPods:
Simply add the following line to your Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftLint'
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue, could you be a bit more specific? swiftlint seems to be executed so why all this info about installation etc?

Comment: see SS error, i disabled identifier_name violation and excluded Pods.. Why still those are scanning?

Comment: So the problem is not with the excluded rules but with the pods being scanned.

Comment: What would be solution?

Comment: Sorry I forgot a ? at the end, that was a question to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its better way to install lint package in system instead installing pods

1.This repo has SwiftLint.pkg. download and install it in your system
https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases

2. Hit brew install swiftlint

3.Add below Run Script phase in Xcode.

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

4. Build & Run the project and you are good to go.
   **Don't forget to add .swiftlint.yml in your project**

I have used exclude/disabled_rules as below for reference which is working

```
excluded:
  - Pods
  - ./*/*Core
  - ./*/*GraphQL
  - ./*GraphQlConfig

disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
  - colon
  - comma
  - control_statement
```